# Error installing cucumber by eclipse marketplace

Tags: eclipse, cucumber

Good afternoon ... It generates the same error. Please perform all the steps mentioned above but this error has not been resolved.

This happens when I want to add cucumber in the eclipse ide by a marketplace

Unable to read repository at https://cucumber.github.io/cucumber-eclipse-update-site-snapshot/content.xml. PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Are you doing this behind a corporate firewall? Perhaps the "Network Connections" sectino of preferences needs to specify your proxy host and port?

Comment: Hello David;
The download was made with the internet in my house and also connected to the VNP but with the company's proxy. But neither works for me. I always get the same error